# Displaying the data a user registers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display a member since date in rails. I have attempted the following:

```
<%= @trainer.signup.date %>

<%= @trainer.registration.date %>
```

This is for their profile, which displays their length of membership on the page.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be looking for `@trainer.created_at`

Comment: Yep this is the one! - Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, would you accept the answer if it helped you @user3349825

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
time_ago_in_words(@trainer.created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(@trainer.signup.date) %>

<%= time_ago_in_words(@trainer.registration.date) %>
```